# How to disable "Reader View" panel in the iOS 13 web app?

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari, progressive-web-apps, ios13

After updating to iOS 13, our web app (Safari -> Add to HomeScreen) has this black "Reader View" panel on top. I know it is possible to remove it, since the Twitter web app does not have it, but I was not able to figure out how they did it...

**Does anyone know how to remove it?**

[image: See attached]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added basic manifest.json and it solved the problem. Except for subdomains...

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "start_url": "example.com",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/"
}
```